# How can I load a file of thousands of images in html?

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, dataset, visualize

Now I have a local folder with 12989 images. The total size is 410MB. On the other hand I have another csv dataset, which has each image's name, main color and some other information. 
So, how can I visualize all the images without calling one by one? Thank you!(if possible, I prefer using d3.js. )

Comment: Add what you have done till now for accomplishing this requirement and provide details of where exactly you are stuck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use bunch of `rect` elements to show each image's color, then show the full image on mouseover. There are countless ways to arrange them, depending on what data you have and what you're trying to show. Some examples:

- [list](http://roadtolarissa.com/film-strips/)
- [map](http://roadtolarissa.com/meteors/)
- [grid](https://www.nytimes.com/times-insider/2014/06/27/detroits-troubles-a-mosaic-says-what-words-cant/)

Comment: In the example of "list", I saw the image source is a file with extension .t. It's a file with thousands of images. `<img id = "img" src="movieStills\Argo\1.jpg.t" height="404" width="720"/>` So how can I covert a file with huge amount of images into a file like that? Thank you!

Comment: I don't remember exactly, something like https://askubuntu.com/questions/135477/how-can-i-scale-all-images-in-a-folder-to-the-same-width